# Why did this npm start script for less/css run without having made any changes?

Tags: css, npm, less, package.json, npm-scripts

I have attempted to adapt some course material to use less instead of sass/scss in the automated startup tasks.

I had these scripts in package.json  :

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "npm run watch:all",
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "lite": "lite-server",
   "less": "lessc ./css/*.less ./css/*.css",
   "watch:less": "onchange \"./css/*.less\" -- npm run less",
   "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:less\" \"npm run lite\""
 },
```

Unfortunately, the first time i ran it, it overwrote my existing styles.css by apparently running less on the (at the time, outdated) .less file, even though no changes had been made to it. Why?

Since, I changed the project structure and scripts to:

```
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "less": "lessc ./src/styles.less ./css/styles.css",
    "watch:less": "onchange \"./src/styles.less\" -- npm run less",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:less\" \"npm run lite\""
```

Now, it works as expected - overwriting the styles.css whenever I change styles.less.

I don't understand what about the original form caused it to run the less command immediately. I am new at this. What should I know about npm scripts to understand this and avoid any potential related issues?